# Implementing Graphs on KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to Kivy so this might be a simple error that I am missing.

Ive been trying to implement a graph into my GUI, when I looked it up the main way of doing this is matplotlib. I decided to take an example from online to prototype this, however, when I run the code I receive an error:

> KeyError: 'kivy.garden.matplotlib'

This is my current code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  
# importing numpy
import numpy as np
from kivy.garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
  
# importing kivyapp
from kivy.app import App
  
# importing kivy builder
from kivy.lang import Builder
  
  
# this is the main class which will 
# render the whole application
class uiApp(App):
  
    def build(self):
        self.str = Builder.load_string(""" 
  
BoxLayout:
    layout:layout
      
    BoxLayout:
      
        id:layout
      
                                """)
  
        signal = [7, 89.6, 45.-56.34]
  
        signal = np.array(signal)
          
        # this will plot the signal on graph
        plt.plot(signal)
          
        # setting x label
        plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
          
        # setting y label
        plt.ylabel('signal (norm)')
        plt.grid(True, color='lightgray')
          
        # adding plot to kivy boxlayout
        self.str.layout.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return self.str
  
  
# running the application
uiApp().run()
```

I have tried to uninstall and install `kivy-garden`, I have also uninstalled and reinstalled `Matplotlib`, I still have not solved my error.

Are there any ideas on ways to fix this or alternate methods to present a graph on kivy/kivyMD.